# Find occurrences of a value in a numpy array and assign it appropriate weights

Tags: python, numpy, aggregate

I have a text file of close to 1 million lines.It has 2 columns.Column 1 has numbers from 0-99 and column has 4 sizes ranging from S,M,L,XL.  The numbers from 0 to 99 keep repeating themselves in the 1 million lines with a different sizes as follows:

```
11 S
19 S
19 M
19 M
63 L
14 S
11 L
63 XL
14 S
11 L
63 XL
```

My objective is to find a final size for each number.The plan of action is to find the occurrence of each number,find the size for each occurrence and then assign a final size to number for the maximum occurrences of a size.

**Expected output :**

```
11 L
14 S
19 M
63 XL
```

Because of the size of the dataset,I am having a look at numpy,not that I have any prior experience with it.
I have started by creating a basic numpy array as follows:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('size_data.txt')
```

this does create a numpy array.However,from whatever documentation i have read till now,it does not look like there is a direct way of doing what I want to accomplish.Can some one give me some pointers on how to move forward ?

Comment: Please provide the expected output.

Comment: @Ashwini..the expected output is numbers from 1-99,not repeated,and an appropriate size for each number

Comment: @ashwini..provided the expected output

Comment: Use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html). You need to `groupby(size)`, then aggregate each group using a custom aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by applying [`numpy.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) on reversed version of the first column received from the file. Reversing is required because other wise it(`return_index=True`) will return the indices of first occurrence found of an item from the start.

```
>>> arr = np.loadtxt('foo.txt', dtype=object)
>>> _, indices = np.unique(arr[:, 0][::-1], return_index=True)
>>> arr[::-1][indices]
array([['11', 'L'],
       ['14', 'S'],
       ['19', 'M'],
       ['63', 'XL']], dtype=object)
# or
>>> arr[len(arr) - indices - 1]
array([['11', 'L'],
       ['14', 'S'],
       ['19', 'M'],
       ['63', 'XL']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: ,while this does give the item frequency,what i need is the the size associated with each number..for eg in the data, 11 has one S and 2 L and so the final output should calculate the size of 11 as L since it occurs the maximum amount of times..

Comment: @Amistad Well that's why I asked for actual expected output rather than a comment explaining the output. Update the question with the desired result.

Comment: @ashwini..i overshot the gun a bit with excitement..don't think the output is exactly as i want..for eg..19 comes up twice with different sizes..i am looking for unique numbers with just one size..

Comment: @Amistad So did I :D. Hold on a minute. For to reverse the actual array before indexing it again.

Comment: @ashwini..i had one more question which should be right up your alley..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320873/replace-values-of-a-numpy-array-by-values-from-another-numpy-array

Answer (score 1):

Use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html). You need to `groupby(size)`, then aggregate each group using a custom aggregation, in this case the very helpful `collections.Counter.most_common(n=1)`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

dat.groupby('Id').aggregate(lambda grp: Counter(grp).most_common(1)[0][0] )

   Size
Id     
11    L
14    S
19    M
63   XL
```

Comment: this is also nice and elegant..i had a similar problem ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320873/replace-values-of-a-numpy-array-by-values-from-another-numpy-array ... could you please have a look at that..