# Replace values of a numpy array by values from another numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

i have a 1000 * 1000 numpy array with 1 million values which was created as follows :

```
>>import numpy as np
>>data = np.loadtxt('space_data.txt')
>> print (data)
>>[[ 13.  15.  15. ...,  15.  15.  16.]
   [ 14.  13.  14. ...,  13.  15.  16.]
   [ 16.  13.  13. ...,  13.  15.  17.]
   ..., 
   [ 14.   15.  14. ...,  14.  14.  13.]
   [ 15.   15.  16. ...,  16.  15.  14.]
   [ 14.   13.  16. ...,  16.  16.  16.]]
```

I have another numpy array which which has 2 columns as follows:

```
>> print(key)
>>[[ 10.,   S],
   [ 11.,   S],
   [ 12.,   S],
   [ 13.,   M],
   [ 14.,   L],
   [ 15.,   S],
   [ 16.,   S],
   ...,
   [ 92.,   XL],
   [ 93.,   M],
   [ 94.,   XL],
   [ 95.,   S]]
```

What i would basically want is to replace each element of of the data array with corresponding element in the second column of the key array like this..

```
>> print(data)
>>[[ M  S  S ...,  S  S  S]
   [ L   M  L ...,  M  S  S]
   [ S   M  M ...,  M  S  XL]
   ..., 
   [ L   S  L ...,  L  L  M]
   [ S   S  S ...,  S  S  L]
   [ L   M  S ...,  S  S  S]]
```

Comment: Please correct your code snippet for `data` as it's wrong (missing commas). This can confuse other users of the data type.

Comment: are S, M, L ... variable names or strings?

Comment: well, if data is a numpy array of floats, you cannot replace in place its elements by strings, so you need to create another list

Comment: @ha9u63ar..i copied this straight from the terminal..i printed the array and there were no commas..

Comment: @Amistad Also post the repr versions of NumPy arrays: `print(repr(data))`

Comment: @Julien..i will edit the question then..let S=1,M=2,L=3 and XL=4..is there a way for this then..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python dicts are a natural choice for mapping from keys to values.  NumPy has
no direct equivalent of a dict. But it does have arrays which can do fast integer indexing. For example,

```
In [153]: keyarray = np.array(['S','M','L','XL'])

In [158]: data = np.array([[0,2,1], [1,3,2]])

In [159]: keyarray[data]
Out[159]: 
array([['S', 'L', 'M'],
       ['M', 'XL', 'L']], 
      dtype='|S2')
```

So if we could massage your `key` array into one that looked like this:

```
In [161]: keyarray
Out[161]: 
array(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'M', 'L',
       'S', 'S', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'XL', 'M', 'XL', 'S'], 
      dtype='|S32')
```

So that 10 maps to 'S' in the sense that `keyarray[10]` equals `S`, and so forth:

```
In [162]: keyarray[10]
Out[162]: 'S'
```

then we could produce the desired result with `keyarray[data]`.

---

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array( [[ 13.,   15.,  15.,  15.,  15.,  16.],
                  [ 14.,   13.,  14.,  13.,  15.,  16.],
                  [ 16.,   13.,  13.,  13.,  15.,  17.],
                  [ 14.,   15.,  14.,  14.,  14.,  13.],
                  [ 15.,   15 ,  16.,  16.,  15.,  14.],
                  [ 14.,   13.,  16.,  16.,  16.,  16.]])

key = np.array([[ 10., 'S'],
                [ 11., 'S'],
                [ 12., 'S'],
                [ 13., 'M'],
                [ 14., 'L'],
                [ 15., 'S'],
                [ 16., 'S'],
                [ 17., 'XL'],
                [ 92., 'XL'],
                [ 93., 'M'],
                [ 94., 'XL'],
                [ 95., 'S']])

idx = np.array(key[:,0], dtype=float).astype(int)
n = idx.max()+1
keyarray = np.empty(n, dtype=key[:,1].dtype)
keyarray[:] = ''
keyarray[idx] = key[:,1]

data = data.astype('int')
print(keyarray[data])
```

yields

```
[['M' 'S' 'S' 'S' 'S' 'S']
 ['L' 'M' 'L' 'M' 'S' 'S']
 ['S' 'M' 'M' 'M' 'S' 'XL']
 ['L' 'S' 'L' 'L' 'L' 'M']
 ['S' 'S' 'S' 'S' 'S' 'L']
 ['L' 'M' 'S' 'S' 'S' 'S']]
```

Note that `data = data.astype('int')` is assuming that the floats in `data` can be *uniquely* mapped to `int`s. That appears to be the case with your data, but it is not true for arbitrary floats. For example, `astype('int')` maps both 1.0 and 1.5 map to 1.

```
In [167]: np.array([1.0, 1.5]).astype('int')
Out[167]: array([1, 1])
```

Answer (score 3):

An un-vectorized linear approach will be to use a dictionary here:

```
dct = dict(keys)
# new array is required if dtype is different or it it cannot be casted
new_array = np.empty(data.shape, dtype=str)
for index in np.arange(data.size):
    index = np.unravel_index(index, data.shape)
    new_array[index] = dct[data[index]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[ 13.,  15.,  15.],
   [ 14.,  13.,  14. ],
   [ 16.,  13.,  13. ]])

key = [[ 10.,   'S'],
   [ 11.,   'S'],
   [ 12.,   'S'],
   [ 13.,   'M'],
   [ 14.,   'L'],
   [ 15.,   'S'],
   [ 16.,   'S']]

data2 = np.zeros(data.shape, dtype=str)

for k in key:
    data2[data == k[0]] = k[1]
```

Comment: This should be fast enough if number of items in `key` array are not huge, but will be quadratic if `key`'s size increases.

Comment: indeed, looks like there should be 86 entries in key maybe ... otherwise is probably the fastest

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create a dataframe out of your 'data' array and make a dictionary out of your 'key' array. 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([[ 13.,  15.,  15.],
               [ 14.,  13.,  14. ],
               [ 16.,  13.,  13. ]])
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
key  = dict({10 : 'S',11 : 'S', 12 : 'S', 13 : 'M',14:'L',15:'S',16:'S'})
# Replace the values in newly created dataframe and convert that into array.
data_df.replace(key,inplace = True)

data = np.array(data_df)
print(data)
```

This will be the output:

```
[['M' 'S' 'S']
['L' 'M' 'L']
['S' 'M' 'M']]
```