# How to substitute numbers of a numpy array with strings of a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a numpy array and want to replace its values with some strings. I checked [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320873/replace-values-of-a-numpy-array-by-values-from-another-numpy-array) but could not solve my issue. My strings are in a list:

```
names=['base', 'middle', 'top']
```

my list has three strings and it means I have also three numbers in my array:

```
import numpy as np
numbers=np.array([[3., 1., 2., 2.], [1., 2., 3., 1.]])
```

To map names with numbers I have this logic: from the first name until the last, numbers decrease. I mean first name matches the highest number (`'base' : 3.`), next name the second highest (`'middle' : 2.`) and last name equals the lowest (`'top' : 1.`). Finally I want to have my array as:

```
subs_arr= np.array([['base', 'top', 'middle', 'middle'], ['top', 'middle', 'base', 'top']])
```

Is ther any way to do it automatically (without the need for mapping names with numbers) in python? I do appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: `subs_arr = np.array(names)[(numbers-1).astype(np.int)]` where `numbers` should start with 0 since a python index start with 0. However this solution is the same as the one suggested in your link, so I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace values of a numpy array by values from another numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320873/replace-values-of-a-numpy-array-by-values-from-another-numpy-array)

Comment: Dear @obchardon, thanks for your help. Honestly, after reading that solution I still could not figure out my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about smth like this:

```
import numpy as np
numbers = np.array([[3., 1., 2., 2.], [1., 2., 3., 1.]]).astype(int)-1
names = np.array(['top', 'middle', 'base'])

subs_arr = names[numbers]
```

output:

```
subs_arr = 
[['base' 'top' 'middle' 'middle']
 ['top' 'middle' 'base' 'top']]
```

Comment: Dear @yan ziselman, maybe replacing 1 with np.min(numbers) works better, isnt it?

Comment: that would depend on the use case and how you form the array 'numbers'